# Http Post Internal Server Error 500 in Web Api & WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using WPF as Client and Web api as Service. For add new event click button and update button in WPF not returning to http post action in api controller and also returning error Internal server error.
Http Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostEvent(EventFormModel event1)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new CreateOrUpdateEventCommand(event1.EventId, event1.EventAgenda, event1.Description, event1.EventDate, event1.Location, event1.UserId);
        var result = commandBus.Submit(command);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, event1);
            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = event1.EventId });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

WPF click event:

```
private async void btnNewEvent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            var event1 = new Event()
            {
                EventAgenda = txtAgenda.Text,
                Description = txtEventDescription.Text,
                Location=txtLocation.Text,
                UserId=Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text),
                EventId=Convert.ToInt32(txtEventId.Text),
                EventDate=Convert.ToDateTime(dateEventDate.Text),
            };
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:40926/api/Event");
            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Event", event1).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("added" + response);
                txtAgenda.Text = "";
                txtEventDescription.Text = "";
                txtLocation.Text = "";
                txtUserId.Text = "";
                txtEventId.Text = "";
                dateEventDate.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
```

}
Event class in WPF application:

```
 public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Agenda Required")]
    //[Display(Name = "Movie Name")]
    public string EventAgenda { get; set; }
  //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location Required")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Required")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
   // public string ReminderType { get; set; }
}
```

I used breakpoints near post action and also click event. but in click event near 
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Event", event1).Result; not returing to api post method and returning Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error). Similar issue for Update also

-Thanks Sindhu

Answer (score 0):

You included some parts of the URI twice.

```
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:40926/api/Event");
            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Event", event1).Result;
```

You duplicated "api/Event". And would get the URI, api/Event/api/Event/. For your BaseAddress you only need hostname and port.

e.g.

```
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:40926");
   var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Event", event1).Result;
```

Also you are getting a 500 Internal Server error from somewhere else in your sever code. I can't where right now.